# How to parse json output?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I tried to parse this url 
[https://esewa.com.np/epay/transdetails?pid=AddFund-C-11970239-    9625960&amt=100&scd=nprhosting&rid=00C3LF0](https://esewa.com.np/epay/transdetails?pid=AddFund-C-11970239-9625960&amt=100&scd=nprhosting&rid=00C3LF0)

```
{
"code":"00",
"msg":"Success",
"txnDetail": {
                 "txnCode":"00C3LF0",
                 "amt":"100.0",
                 "date":"2015-07-16 23:44:18.0",
                 "payerId":"dipsnwc@gmail.com",
                 "status":"COMPLETE",
                 "pid":"AddFund-C-11970239-9625960",
                 "txAmt":"0",
                 "psc":"0",
                 "pdc":"0"
             }
  }
```

Like this

```
$fields = array(
'pid' => "AddFund-C-11970239-9625960";
'amt' => "100.0";
'scd' => "nprhosting";
'rid' => "00C3LF0"; 
);


$field2 = json_encode($fields);

$url = "https://esewa.com.np/epay/transdetails";

 // Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($field2))
);
// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
//

///Deocde Json
$data = (json_decode($result, true));
var_dump($data);
$message =$data['msg']; 
$status =$data['txnDetail']['status'];
echo $message;
echo $status;
```

Still no output ??

Comment: Check your http servers error log file. That is where php posts information about errors at runtime.

Comment: The data you're adding to URL is just a query string. You shouldn't `json_encode()` it.

Comment: i tried both ways.. still something not ok

Answer (score 0):

Array is incorrect, remove `:`:

```
$fields = array(
'pid' => "AddFund-C-11970239-9625960",
'amt' => "100.0",
'scd' => "nprhosting",
'rid' => "00C3LF0"
);
```

and try

```
$url = "http://examplesite.com/epay/transdetails?" . http_build_query($fields);
```

Chuck the `POSTFIELDS` and `HTTPHEADER`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

The parameters are expected to be as GET(as per the link you have provided), keep it simple.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159513/861704) answer for better understanding on how to send HTTP GET request with PHP CURL.

Comment: Request method may be post/get as in dev. guide in this case. I tried $url as above but still no  outcome

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and worked..

```
$url = 'https://example.com/epay/transdetails?pid=AddFund-C-11970239-9625960&amt=100&scd=nprsite&rid=00C3LF0';
$data  = file_get_contents($url);
$arr =  json_decode($data,true);
echo $arr['txnDetail']['status'];
print_r($arr);
```